# C API for Quantifiers

Tags: z3

I want to solve constraints that contain quantifiers using Z3 C API.
I am struggling to use the functions like "Z3_mk_exists()" as I don't find any example either online or in the test examples in the tar file.
I don't exactly understand all the arguments required by these functions and exact significance of them.
Can anyone help?

Thanks.
Kaustubh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a complete example with universal quantifiers. Comments are inline:

```
Z3_config cfg = Z3_mk_config();
Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "MODEL", "true");
Z3_context ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
Z3_sort intSort = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
/* Some constant integers */
Z3_ast zero  = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 0, intSort);
Z3_ast one   = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 1, intSort);
Z3_ast two   = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 2, intSort);
Z3_ast three = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 3, intSort);
Z3_ast four  = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 4, intSort);
Z3_ast five  = Z3_mk_int(ctx, 5, intSort);
```

We create an uninterpreted function for fibonacci: `fib(n)`. We'll specify its meaning with a universal quantifier.

```
Z3_func_decl fibonacci = Z3_mk_fresh_func_decl(ctx, "fib", 1, &intSort, intSort);

/* fib(0) and fib(1) */
Z3_ast fzero = Z3_mk_app(ctx, fibonacci, 1, &zero);
Z3_ast fone  = Z3_mk_app(ctx, fibonacci, 1, &one);
```

We're starting to specify the meaning of `fib(n)`. The base cases don't require quantifiers. We have `fib(0) = 0` and `fib(1) = 1`.

```
Z3_ast fib0 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, fzero, zero);
Z3_ast fib1 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, fone,  one);
```

This is a bound variable. They're used within quantified expressions. Indices should start from `0`. We have only one in this case.

```
Z3_ast x = Z3_mk_bound(ctx, 0, intSort);
```

This represents `fib(_)`, where `_` is the bound variable.

```
Z3_ast fibX = Z3_mk_app(ctx, fibonacci, 1, &x);
```

The pattern is what will trigger the instantiation. We use `fib(_)` again. This means (more or less) that Z3 will instantiate the axiom whenever it sees `fib("some term")`.

```
Z3_pattern pattern = Z3_mk_pattern(ctx, 1, &fibX);
```

This symbol is only used for debugging as far as I understand. It gives a name to the `_`.

```
Z3_symbol someName = Z3_mk_int_symbol(ctx, 0);

/* _ > 1 */
Z3_ast xGTone = Z3_mk_gt(ctx, x, one);
Z3_ast xOne[2] = { x, one };
Z3_ast xTwo[2] = { x, two };
/* _ - 1 */
Z3_ast fibXminusOne = Z3_mk_sub(ctx, 2, xOne);
/* _ - 2 */
Z3_ast fibXminusTwo = Z3_mk_sub(ctx, 2, xTwo);
Z3_ast toSum[2] = { Z3_mk_app(ctx, fibonacci, 1, &fibXminusOne), Z3_mk_app(ctx, fibonacci, 1, &fibXminusTwo) };
/* f(_ - 1) + f(_ - 2) */
Z3_ast fibSum = Z3_mk_add(ctx, 2, toSum);
```

This is now the body of the axiom. It says: `_ > 1 => (fib(_) = fib(_ - 1) + fib(_ - 2)`,  where _ is the bound variable.

```
Z3_ast axiomTree = Z3_mk_implies(ctx, xGTone, Z3_mk_eq(ctx, fibX, fibSum));
```

At last we can build a quantifier tree, using the pattern, the bound variable, its name and the axiom body. (`Z3_TRUE` says its a forall quantifier). The `0` in the argument list specifies the priority. The Z3 doc recommends to use `0` if you don't know what to put.

```
Z3_ast fibN = Z3_mk_quantifier(ctx, Z3_TRUE, 0, 1, &pattern, 1, &intSort, &someName, axiomTree);
```

We finally add the axiom(s) the to context.

```
Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, fib0);
Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, fib1);
Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, fibN);
```